# How do I resize my ext4 partition and add the free size to an NTFS one?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-11.04, gparted

I have a 500GB HDD with the following partitions. From Windows 7 I cannot resize the `sda6` (ext4) partition. I want to make it about 100GB and the free size to add to the `sda7` (NTFS) partition.

Can anyone give me a hint? Until then I'll try the Ubuntu Live CD.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just booted from Hiren's Boot CD v13, works just fine (I wanted an answer that doesn't involve live cd's)

Comment: It's a pain to resize partitions that are currently mounted. I used to use Paragon Partition Manager in Windows, that reboots and runs it before windows starts. I found gparted to work faster, and like being able to browse and do web things on my USB while it's partitioning my drives.

Comment: in windows, i'm using too Paragon Partition Manager, it is ok, but in this case it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Boot from an Ubuntu Live CD, run GParted from it. You should be able to resize both partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Right click /dev/sda6 in the list, and resize it. Then rightclick /dev/sda3 in the list and resize that to shrink it. Now you should be able to expand /dev/sda2.

Since sda6 is in the extended sda3, it's an extra step. You'll need to do it from a bootable disk or USB. Parted Magic is great for this, but anything with gparted will do fine.

If you have trouble resizing sda3, move all the free space to the far right of it.